# Number extraction from strings using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

i have this C# code that i found and then improved upon for my needs, but now i would like to make it work for all numeric data types.

```
    public static int[] intRemover (string input)
    {
        string[] inputArray = Regex.Split (input, @"\D+");
        int n = 0;
        foreach (string inputN in inputArray) {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (inputN)) {
                n++;
            }
        }
        int[] intarray = new int[n];
        n = 0;
        foreach (string inputN in inputArray) {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (inputN)) {
                intarray [n] = int.Parse (inputN);
                n++;
            }
        }
        return intarray;
    }
```

This works well for trying to extract whole number integers out of strings but the issue that i have is that the regex expression i am using is not setup to account for numbers that are negative or numbers that contain a decimal point in them. My goal in the end like i said is to make a method out of this that works upon all numeric data types. Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: You will definitely want to move away from using the `int` datatype then. Perhaps use `decimal`. Unfortunately my Regex isn't up to scratch so I cannot help you with an answer

Comment: When you say "all numeric data types" do you want it to handle exponents, hexa-decimal etc? or do you just need +/- and the decimal point handling?

Comment: NumberExtracter would be a better name. How would you return those numbers? As you can't return a list of int with double in the middle. Also how big can these numbers get? Maybe you'd need to create a custom class that can hold any number.

Comment: what would your input look like

Comment: @musefan i am making similar methods like this for each data type, i just used the int version for the post.

Comment: @BuddhiP for now i just want it to handle +/- and decimal numbers.

Comment: @MrFox here is the code i have been using to retrieve the results from the process
string mystring = Console.ReadLine();
   int[]myArray= StringCleaner.intRemover(mystring);
   foreach (int i in myArray) {
    Console.WriteLine (Convert.ToString (i));
like i said at the top of this comment i am planning on writing alternate methods that can handle the various data types and then combining them into a class(with a better name most likely).

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ the input would be a string so it could be anything from a user input to just a hard coded nonsensical mashup of numbers and characters.

Comment: @MrFox the text editor here ate my code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `match` it instead of splitting it

```
public static decimal[] intRemover (string input)
{
    return Regex.Matches(input,@"[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?")//this returns all the matches in input
                .Cast<Match>()//this casts from MatchCollection to IEnumerable<Match>
                .Select(x=>decimal.Parse(x.Value))//this parses each of the matched string to decimal
                .ToArray();//this converts IEnumerable<decimal> to an Array of decimal
}
```

---

`[+-]?` matches `+` or `-` 0 or 1 time

`\d+` matches 1 to many digits

`(\.\d+)?` matches a (decimal followed by 1 to many digits) 0 to 1 time

---

Simplified form of the above code

```
    public static decimal[] intRemover (string input)
    {
        int n=0;
        MatchCollection matches=Regex.Matches(input,@"[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?");
        decimal[] decimalarray = new decimal[matches.Count];

        foreach (Match m in matches) 
        {
                decimalarray[n] = decimal.Parse (m.Value);
                n++;
        }
        return decimalarray;
    }
```

Comment: i'm still pretty new to c# and programming in general, could you give me a quick rundown of what is going on with that code? 
also i think i may be missing the proper reference to use this code, i dropped it in and it couldnt find definitions for ".cast" and a few other things. what do i need to reference to make it work?

Comment: @AlexZywicki you need to include  `System.Linq`

Comment: its throwing an exception because the array index is out of bounds. in theory i could just make the array bigger, but the way i had it setup before worked for in a way that the array size was decided based on the result of the regex.split that way it could account for almost any size of input and aways come back within the bounds of the array.

Comment: the code runs now but it is still removing the decimal point, but it is accepting negatives! so that solves half of the issue

Comment: @AlexZywicki numbers like `444.` `554.` doesnt make sense cuz the `.` is redundant..

Comment: if i put in 10.10 it still just gives me 10

Comment: @AlexZywicki for input like `4.10.10` it would give `4.10` and `10`...this is expected behaviour

Comment: that is strange, i must have something wrong in my code. i will enter it again and see if it works. thanks for all of the help btw

Comment: this is the code i have in there at the moment, as far as i can tell it is what you said to use.

public static decimal[] decimalRemover (string input)
  {
   int n=0;
   MatchCollection matches=Regex.Matches(input,@"[+-]?\d+(\.\d*)?");
   decimal[] decimalarray = new decimal[matches.Count];
   
   foreach (Match m in matches) 
   {
    decimalarray[n] = decimal.Parse (m.Value);
    n++;
   }
   return decimalarray;
  }

Comment: i dont know how to get the code to format correctly on here yet sorry

Comment: @AlexZywicki your code **worked** on my machine..what `input` are you giving and what `output` are you expecting

Comment: i was giving 10.10 and expecting to get 10.10 back from it. this is the code i have been using to pass and receive the input and output.

string mystring = Console.ReadLine();
   decimal[]myArray= StringCleaner.decimalRemover(mystring);
   foreach (int i in myArray) {
    Console.WriteLine (Convert.ToString (i));

Comment: @AlexZywicki it was a very small mistake..;)..foreach should use `decimal` **NOT** `int`

Comment: @AlexZywicki your `foreach(int` should be `foreach(decimal`

Comment: @AlexZywicki if that has helped you..you can accept the answer

Comment: gladly, but seeing that this is the first time i have used this website i do not no how. but if you could tell me i will do so

Answer (score 1):

try modifying you regular expression like this:

```
 @"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?"
```

Comment: Indeed. Thanks @Rawling, I had it escaped, but Stackoverflow ate my backslash. I had to escape that too.