# How do I Extract negative and positive int from a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net

The code will display `ten` when I need it to display the error message

```
int _userInt = 0;
string _checkForNumbers = "Mitchell, -10";
var _intInput = string.Join("", _checkForNumbers.Where(char.IsDigit));
int.TryParse(_intInput, out _userInt);
if(_userInt < 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please only enter positive numbers");
  Console.ReadKey(true);
}
else
{
  Console.Write($"{_userInt}");
  Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: you should consider using Console.Write(_userInt) instead

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thank you for posting your first question.  For the best possible answers questions should be clear about what you are trying to achieve and what you have done to get to where you are now.  There is a [great article about how to write good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please consider having a read of it and editing your question to be clearer about what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think This simple linq should work,

```
int temp = 0;
var strInt = checkForNumbers.Split().First(x => int.TryParse(x, out temp));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try extracting numbers with regex

```
public static decimal[] intRemover (string input)
{
    int n=0;
    MatchCollection matches=Regex.Matches(input,@"[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?");
    decimal[] decimalarray = new decimal[matches.Count];

    foreach (Match m in matches) 
    {
            decimalarray[n] = decimal.Parse (m.Value);
            n++;
    }
    return decimalarray;
}
```

[Number extraction from strings using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13641672/number-extraction-from-strings-using-regex)

Answer (score 0):

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
     string src = "Mitchell, 4-10-5arbitrary-text3";
     var matches = Regex.Matches(src, @"-?\d+");
     matches[0].Value; //4
     matches[1].Value; //-10;
     matches[2].Value; //-5
     matches[3].Value; //3
```

Those Value are `string`, you need to call `int.Parse` to get integer value

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)
[TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_regular_expressions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

public void TryThis()

```
    {
        string pattern = @"\-*\d+";
        string value="Mitchell, -10";
        Match oMatch=Regex.Match(value,pattern);

        if (int.Parse(oMatch.Value) < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(oMatch.Value);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(oMatch.Value);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this will select ----1 as a number as well